# "Unflattening" a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Imagine we have a list with some hierarchical structure:

```
list = {{{2,3},{2,4}},{{{3,4}}},{{5,6},{7,8}}};
```

Which we then flatten to some level in order to process the data points:

```
Flatten[list,1]
>> {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}
```

We then do "something" to change the value of the elements in the list, without increasing or decreasing the number of elements:

```
>> {{5*10^9, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {191991, 6}, {7, 8}}
```

Can we reverse the flattening procedure to go back to a list of the form:

```
>> {{{5*10^9,3},{2,4}},{{{3,4}}},{{191991,6},{7,8}}};
```

Comment: `Partition` is essentially the inverse of `Flatten`

Comment: @bill s Oh, I know about Partition.  My question is how we can kind of save the previous structure of the list prior to flattening, and then reapply this hierarchical structuring (which can pretty much be arbitrary).

Comment: I'd presume you can't actually save the previous structure. What you might be able to do is simply map the new elements back to list, ie. replacing elements in the old list with ones in the new list in order. This should be possible since you aren't increasing or decreasing the number of elements.

Comment: @bills I feel `Internal-Deflatten` is also a candidate for the inverse of `Flatten`, and is worth mentioning :). See [Szabolcs answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/807/4330) in the Q&A about undocumented functions. But yeah I guess it doesn't really help.

Comment: related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45293/66

Comment: Code golf post inspired by this question: http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/43018/unflatten-an-array

Comment: Hi guys, can one use the new `ArrayReshape`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### Edit

As described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/45293/187), the solution below leaks symbols in the global namespace. This can be prevented by using this shorter equivalent:

```
unflatten[l_, o_] := Module[{i = 1, l1 = Flatten[l]},
  Function[Null, l1[[i++]], {Listable}][o]
]
```

---

#### Original

You can *unflatten* every list with the same number of elements as long as you still have your original `list`. When you really overwrite your original `list` with its flattened version, then the structure is lost forever.

Let me give an alternative approach which should work with all kinds of elements. Additionally, this function might have a *nerdy* touch, because it is not quite obvious why it does what it does

```
unflatten[l_, o_] := Module[{f, i = 1, l1 = Flatten[l]},
  Attributes[f] = {Listable}; f[_] := l1[[i++]]; f[o]]
```

When we now take a somehow deeply structured list `orig`, we can restructure the list `{1,2,3,4}` in exactly the same way

```
orig = {{{}, {Exp[1]}, 3, {{{{a}}}, c}}};
unflatten[Range[4], orig]

(* {{{}, {1}, 2, {{{{3}}}, 4}}} *)
```

---

**Spoiler alert**

> OK, to give some hints: Above we want to structure the list `l` exactly the same way as `o`. The function `f` doesn't really do something. Every time it is called with any argument, it returns the next element from the list `l` by using the counter `i`. The important thing is, that `f` has the attribute `Listable` which makes that it is first distributed to all elements in the list, no matter how deeply they are nested. If `f` finally meets a list element, it returns the replacement element and the list structure is preserved. Therefore, the whole approach works because `Listable` functions return the same list structure as their arguments and the order in which the elements are visited is the correct one.

Comment: @halirutan Nice.

Comment: Adding to the nerdiness, can we make unflatten into a nestedRotate by setting `f[_] := l1[[++i /. Length@l1 + 1 -> 1]];` or something similar?

Comment: A memory / symbol leak has been discovered for your code  - which is otherwise very neat and elegant, [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45293/how-to-fix-this-memory-leak). Perhaps, it is a good idea to update to one of the alternatives posted there, or some other one?

Comment: @LeonidShifrin I posted an alternative which hopefully doesn't leak any more. Thanks for pinging me on this!

Comment: @halirutan Welcome :) Actually, the minimal change would've been just using `SetAttributes[f, Listable]` in place of `Attributes[f]={Listable}`, but of course there are many ways, as usual in M.

Comment: (Just to put it here, too) The reason `f` leaks is that you've destroyed the `Temporary` attribute

Answer (score 6):

I faced the same problem a while ago. Here's my initial code:

```
copyPartition[A_, B_] := Module[{i = 0}, Map[A[[++i]]&,B,{-1}]]
```

It works fine most of the time:

```
A = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i};  
B = {1, {2, 3}, {4, {5}, 6}, {7, {{8}, {9}}}};  
copyPartition[A,B]
(*  {a, {b, c}, {d, {e}, f}, {g, {{h}, {i}}}} *)
```

But change the `i` in `A` to `i$`:

```
A = {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i$};
copyPartition[A,B]
(*  {a, {b, c}, {d, {e}, f}, {g, {{h}, {8}}}} *)
```

The `i$` got evaluated -- a situation that's not likely to occur in practice, but I still didn't like it.
My solution was to do everything twice:

```
copyPartishun[A_, B_] := Map[A[[#]]&, Block[{i = 0}, Map[++i&,B,{-1}]], {-1}]
```

That solves the problem, but it's slow, so I asked in [Mathgroup](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2006/May/msg00368.html).
The best answer was from J. Siehler:

```
partitionedAz[A_, B_] := ReplacePart[B, A, Position[B,_,{-1},Heads->False],
                                     Transpose@{Range@Length@Flatten@B}]
```

Answer (score 6):

#### `` Internal`CopyListStructure ``

***Examples:***

```
orig = {{{}, {Exp[1]}, 3, {{{{a}}}, c}}};

Internal`CopyListStructure[orig, Range[4]]
```

> ```
> {{{}, {1}, 2, {{{{3}}}, 4}}}
> ```

```
list = {{{2, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{{3, 4}}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}};
list1 = Flatten[list, 1];
list1[[1]] = {2, 8};

Internal`CopyListStructure[list, Flatten@list1]
```

> ```
>  {{{2, 8}, {2, 4}}, {{{3, 4}}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}
> ```

Answer (score 5):

One possible solution

```
list = {{{2, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{{3, 4}}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}
```

> {{{2, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{{3, 4}}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}

```
list1 = Flatten[list, 1]
list1[[1]] = {2, 8};
list1
```

> {{2, 3}, {2, 4}, {{3, 4}}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}
>
> {{2, 8}, {2, 4}, {{3, 4}}, {5, 6}, {7, 8}}

```
ReplacePart[list, {Sequence @@ 
    MapThread[#1 -> #2 & , {Position[list, _?(NumberQ[#] &)] , 
    Flatten[list1]}]}]
```

> {{{2, 8}, {2, 4}}, {{{3, 4}}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}}

Answer (score 4):

I prefer the following code. You don't bother to copy the structure; just replace the number in the original list with corresponding one.

```
lstOrigin = {{{2, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{{3, 4}}}, {{5, 6}, {7, 8}}};
answerFlatten = Flatten@{{5*10^9, 3}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}, {191991, 6}, {7, 8}};

Block[{i = 1},
   answerFinal = lstOrigin /. _?NumberQ :> (answerFlatten[[i++]])]
```

The code gives

> {{{5000000000, 3}, {2, 4}}, {{{3, 4}}}, {{191991, 6}, {7, 8}}}

If you do this often, you may probably change the `Block` into a function.

Comment: +1 This seems like a very straightforward approach that guarantees that the structure will be maintained.