# How to fix this memory leak

Tags: memory

I am using [halirutan's code](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30412/13420) in [this thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/30405/unflattening-a-list) to unflatten a list. It works very well but the problem is that the Module's local function `f` is not deleted when the function returns the output and I consequently end up with hundreds of thousands of copies of the symbol of the form `f$xxxx`, which eventually crashes Mathematica. I tried other solutions from the same thread, but they don't seem to work. Is there any workaround?

Comment: This slight change to that code might suffice. `unflatten[l_, o_] := 
 Module[{f, i = 1, l1 = Flatten[l]}, Attributes[f] = {Listable}; 
  f[_] := l1[[i++]]; ll = f[o]; Clear[f]; ll]`

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You beat me to it. Why don't you write this as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The creation of an explicit function `f` can be completely avoided by using the 3rd argument to `Function`. There, you can specify what `Attributes` the anonymous function should have and therefore, you can enforce the same behavior as you did for `f`.

```
unflatten[l_, o_] := Module[{i = 1, l1 = Flatten[l]},
  Function[Null, l1[[i++]], {Listable}][o]
]
```

Comment: That's very neat and works perfectly !

Answer (score 6):

Here is an alternative which is a bit shorter and closer to the original, and still completely free of this leak:

```
unflatten[l_, o_] :=
  Module[{res, f, i = 1, l1 = Flatten[l]},
    Block[{f},
       SetAttributes[f, Listable];
       f[_] := l1[[i++]];
       f[o]]]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can fix that with the following change:

```
unflatten[l_, o_] := 
    Module[{f, i = 1, l1 = Flatten[l]}, 
        SetAttributes[f, Listable]; 
        f[_] := l1[[i++]];
        With[{res = f[o]},
            Clear[f, l1];
            res
        ]
    ]
```

Comment: @LeonidShifrin Thanks, I've changed it, but why do you say it won't work (it worked in my test)? Isn't the `Temporary` attribute only necessary for automatic garbage collection? If I force erase all definitions, is it not the same?

Comment: It's not, because then this variable is not garbage -collected - `Module` only garbage - collects variables with attribute `Temporary`. You can make a simple  experiment to verify that: `Module[{f},f[1] = 1; Clear[f]]`, and then also try `ClearAll`, and monitor the existing symbols in ``Global` `` as you do this.

Comment: Actually, in this case, it seems to not work, no matter whether one uses `Clear` or `ClearAll`. I am a bit puzzled.

Comment: Ok, the statement `Attributes[f]=Listable` is the culprit. You also have to use instead `SetAttributes[f,Listable]`, so that the `Temporary` is preserved.

Comment: This code reduced the number of these extra variables by a third in a test run but the number is still huge. `SetAttributes[f,Listable]`, however, seem to do the trick. I feel lost and can anyone please explain what is going on?

Comment: @Pisto Well, what happens is that the variable is only collected by `Module` *if* it has the attribute `Temporary` *and* it has no `DownValues` or `SubValues` (not sure about `UpValues`, and `OwnValues` are fine. There are also a couple of additional more subtle conditions, but they are not important for this case) at the moment when the execution leaves `Module` (and of course if the return value of `Module` is not some expression containing this local symbol). Now, originally, there were 2 problems: first, the code `Attributes[f] = {Listable}` removes the `Temporary` attribute ...

Comment: @Pisto ... This happens because it explicitly alters all set of attributes, which is one reason why this form is generally not advisable. `SetAttributes` fixes that, because it only adds `Listable` to existing ones, so `Temporary` is retained. Second, we need `Clear` at the end, to remove the `DownValues` which accumulated for `f` during the execution - then we fulfill both conditions and the symbol is garbage-collected.

Comment: @Pisto But have a look at my `Block`-based solution, I think it is a bit more elegant / higher level. It is also robust against exceptions / Aborts inside function's body, which is not an issue here but an issue in general.

Comment: @rm-rf Sorry for my stealing your check-mark with an aggressive marketing :)

Comment: @LeonidShifrin...Thanks. The `Block`-based solution seems to work perfectly. Even the original code is working well now when `SetAttributes[f,Listable]` is used (and even has two fewer variables) !

Comment: @LeonidShifrin No problem :) Also, thanks for noticing the issue with the attributes. I paid no attention to the original code! :D

Comment: @Pisto Actually, now that you mentioned this, it is indeed right. The subtle thing here is that such local symbols with `DownValues` are not collected *only* if they were referenced by some external symbols / expressions. In this case, they are not, so perhaps all this is an overkill and indeed, `SetAttributes` alone is sufficient. I have mentioned this also [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6177/debugging-memory-leaks/6179#6179)