# Undocumented form for Extract

Tags: list-manipulation, undocumented

Prompted by a comments conversation [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/46227/map-structure-of-irregular-list-flatten-then-reconstruct-list-using-structure/46249?noredirect=1#comment137202_46249), here's an interesting (and often performance enhancing) use of `Extract`:

```
target = Join[Range[100], {{1, 2, 3, Range[20]}}];

Rest@Extract[target, {{{}}, {2 ;; 10 ;; 2}, {-1, -1, 1 ;; -1 ;; 2}}]

(* {{2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19}} *)
```

Prepending the `{{}}` to the extraction list appears to suppress the error message one would otherwise get attempting to use `Span`, and it appears that most any valid position/span construct can be used in the extraction list.

The extracted list has an empty list as first element (hence the use of `Rest`). Prepending just `{}` makes the first element the original list.

I've often found this useful instead of mapping over a list of spans (and faster).

This seems similar to the [undocumented extension](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6114/how-to-make-mapat-work-with-span/31173#31173) to `MapAt`

As noted by Mr. Wizard, this does not appear to work in V7, I'm curious what versions it works in.

Comment: Verified to work in *Mathematica* V9.0.1 on MS Windows.

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment until after you posted this.  This structure is OK, but personally I would have used something like: "Is it possible to use Span in Extract?" -- "Yes, since at least v9 there is an undocumented syntax for this, and it performs very well..."  You can rewrite your Q&A like that if you wish, or leave it as it is; either way it gets the information out to people. +1 :-)

Comment: Great find (+1). It looks like extraction list could be prepended with anything that does not trigger an error message: `{{}}`, or `{0}` or `{{101,4,3}}` ...

Comment: It works in *Mathematica* 8.0.4 under Windows.

Comment: New in 3 | Last modified in 8 | Documentation last modified in 5 :-)

Comment: The question example does not work in either 10.0.2 or 10.1.0 under Windows. In both versions the function is returned unevaluated and issues a message.

Answer (score 11):

### Update

I think this behaviour was unintentional. It seems to have been fixed in V10.0.1.

**Evidence that it is unintentional**

The following command crashed the kernel in V9 (and I think V10.0.0)

```
Extract[1, {{}, All}]
```

and printed a funky message too (in V9). Anyway, it makes sense that we should put another pair of brackets around `All`. Then, this was also weird:

```
Extract[1, {{}, {All}}]
```

which used to give `Integer[]`

### Old answer

One thing to point out is that we can still use the third argument of `Extract` if we use `Span`. Indeed `Extract` is now more general/flexible than `Part`, except that you cannot use `Extract` with `Set`. `Extract` appears to work quickly on packedarrays.

**Timings**

Here are some timing comparisons. `Extract` can indeed beat `Part` with `Map` (or like in this answer, `Apply`), as mentioned by rasher in comments. The result here will be a ragged array, so that we cannot suffice with a single call to `Part`. Let

```
max=5*^6;
kk=1000;
mm=max/kk;
target = ConstantArray[Range[kk], mm]; ;
```

We have

```
PackedArrayQ[target]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

If we also let

```
partSpans = Table[{ii, 1 ;; Mod[ii, kk, 1]}, {ii, 1, mm}]; ;
spans = Prepend[properSpans, {{}}];
```

Then

```
(out = Rest@Extract[target, spans]) // Timing // First
(pOut = Part[target, ##] & @@@ partSpans) // Timing // First
pOut === out
```

> ```
> 0.016991  
> 0.020719
> True
> ```

**More and smaller sublists**

For

```
max = 5*^6;
kk = 5;
mm = max/kk;
```

The timings become

> ```
> 0.673268 (*Extract*)
> 1.636892 (*Part*)
> ```

**Extract reduces overhead**

It turns out that the difference in timing between the solutions with `Extract` and `Part` is mainly due to overhead that is caused by `Apply`. Another solution shows that the time taken by `Part` is about the same as that taken by `Extract`, even in this last case. For the timings below, I use the same parameters as in the last case above.

First we do all the overhead

```
(pCode =
    Apply[
     Part,
     Hold@Evaluate@Array[Join[{target}, partSpans[[#]]] &, mm],
     {2}
     ]) // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 5.176928
> ```

Then `Part` is quite quick

```
(p2Out = ReleaseHold[pCode]) // Timing // First
p2Out === out === pOut
```

> ```
> 0.902468 (*Extract took 0.673268 *)
> True
> ```

**Possibly temporary note**

This is a cleaner way to define `pCode` (without the wrapper `Hold`, but using a "delayed definition" instead). Syntax smyntax!

```
ReleaseHold@
   Hold[SetDelayed][
    Hold@pCode,
    Apply[
     Part,
     Hold@Evaluate@Array[Join[{target}, partSpans[[#]]] &, mm],
     {2}
     ]
    ] // Timing // First
```

Comment: Now I will feel bad using `Part` for pure extraction :( but I probably will do that still because of the syntax ;)

Comment: @Kuba `Extract` is more general and can be faster, but if you can use one call to `Part`, `Part` must be faster :). Hm I don't know about syntax arguments :P. I hope in version 10 we get even more control over such things (and we can decide for ourselves whether we like the notation for `Composition` or not :P) :).

Comment: @Kuba see the new last section :P

Comment: `Part` has `[[ ]]` :) and you can e.g. `matrix[[;;,1]]=1`. :) `Composition` can be tricky if you need to extract only tiny part but put that operation inside instead of directly on argument.

Comment: Neat analysis! +1

Comment: Jacob, I converted the one-line answers to comments, as IMHO only your answer has any real substance.