# Convert a list of rules into 2 lists of integers

Tags: list-manipulation, rule

If I have a list of n number of rules, what is a concise way of breaking the data into 2 lists of the first and second part of the rule?

This works, but seems like an unnecessary amount of code to me:

```
data = {
  1 -> 3, 1 -> 3, 1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 2 -> 1, 
  3 -> 2, 3 -> 2, 3 -> 3, 4 -> 1, 4 -> 2, 4 -> 2
};

list1 = First[Partition[Flatten[data /. Rule -> List], 2, 2, 1, {}]~Flatten~{2}]
```

> ```
> {1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4}
> ```

```
list2 = Last[Partition[Flatten[data /. Rule -> List], 2, 2, 1, {}]~Flatten~{2}]
```

> ```
> {3,3,3,3,3,1,2,2,3,1,2,2}
> ```

Comment: {First[#], Last[#]} & /@ data // Transpose

Comment: or `{list1, list2} = {data[[All, 1]], data[[All, 2]]}`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the shortest I can think of:

```
{list1, list2} = Transpose[List @@@ data];

list1
```

> ```
> {1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}
> ```

```
list2
```

> ```
> {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2}
> ```

Answer (score 9):

```
data[[All, #]] & /@ {1, 2}
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2}}
> ```

Comment: or `data[[;; , #]] & /@ {1, 2}` to shave off one character.

Answer (score 9):

```
data // Query[{Keys, Values}]
```

or `Through@{Keys, Values}@data`, or `list1=Keys@data; list2=Values@data`

Comment: Darn, why didn't I think of that. +1

Comment: As far as I'm concerned, `Through[{Keys,Values}[data]]` is the proper answer to this question. +1. Unfortunately, `Through` is a bit of a weird function. We're discussing a new function called maybe `ComposeThrough`, giving  `ComposeThrough[{Keys,Values}, data]` in this example (and of course would have an operator form). This would formalize the `{op,..}` and `<|key->op,...|>` sugar in `Query` (and make it faster).

Comment: @TaliesinBeynon Sounds great but *please* also give it a short form (like `/@` `@*` etc.) so that I'll actually use it.  By the way I'd still like to chat.  Do you have time today?

Comment: `data // Query[{Keys, Values}]` doesn't work using version 10.1.0.0.

Answer (score 8):

user21 and Teake Nutma already posted the two methods I use most often.  Of these I recommend `Part` as I believe it will be faster in general.  Nevertheless these are hardly the *only* ways to accomplish this task.  First, since the expression produced by `List @@@ data` will not be packed `Thread` may be faster than `Transpose`:

```
Thread[List @@@ data]
```

One could also thread over `Rule`, then replace the outer head with `List`:

```
List @@ Thread[data, Rule]
```

From [Undocumented form for Extract](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46261/121) we could also use:

```
Rest @ Extract[data, {{0}, {All, 1}, {All, 2}}]
```

---

#### Benchmarks

A `BenchmarkPlot` for all methods posted so far.

```
f1[a_] := a[[All, #]] & /@ {1, 2};
f2 = Transpose[# /. (a_ -> b_) :> {a, b}] &;
f3 = Transpose[List @@@ #] &;
f4 = Thread[List @@@ #] &;
f5 = List @@ Thread[#, Rule] &;
f6 = Rest@Extract[#, {{0}, {All, 1}, {All, 2}}] &;
f7 = Query[{Keys, Values}];
f8 = {Keys@#, Values@#} &

Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]
g[n_] := Rule @@@ RandomInteger[9, {n, 2}];

BenchmarkPlot[{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8}, g, 2^Range[5, 20], "IncludeFits" -> True]
```

[image] (click for larger)

- [Once again](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56609/121) `Query` has some crazy overhead and should be avoided when performance matters unless inputs are very large.
- `Keys` and `Values` are very fast when used apart from `Query`.
- `List @@ Thread[data, Rule]` is as fast as `Keys` and `Values`, and faster than `Part` and `Extract` which I did not expect.
- As expected `Thread` is slightly faster than `Transpose` with unpacked data.  (`f3` and `f4`)

Comment: Could you add `{First /@ #, Last /@ #} &`?

Comment: @TeakeNutma That is quite a bit slower than the present leaders and I'd rather not clutter the graph any further.  It is the upper line on this plot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/0gKsU.png compared to `f5` and `f8`. (Ignore the legend.)

Answer (score 4):

```
{#1, #2} & @@@ data // Transpose
```

> ```
> {{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `HoldPattern`:

```
data /.HoldPattern[a_ -> b_] :> {a, b} // Transpose
{{1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4}, {3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 
  2, 2}}
```

Comment: You can indeed, but it's not necessary to hold the LHS of the rule. `data /. (a_ -> b_) -> {a, b} // Transpose` or even `data /. Rule -> List // Transpose` work just as fine.

Comment: yep, you're absolutely right.

Comment: @Teake and gpap, you both forgot to localize your pattern names; use `:>` instead!

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I claim a typo!

Comment: done! thanks for the comment - this was written as hastily as they come.