# parsing a list or vector

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a table of elements that generate a list

```
q[i_]=i;
B=Table[q[i],{i,1,50}]
```

I would like to parse the list meaning, take the first 10 elements, then take every other element from 11 to 20, then take every 3rd element from 21 to 50.

Any suggestions?
Thank you all

Answer (score 3):

```
x = Table[i, {i, 1, 50}];

{
  Take[x, 10],
  Take[x, {11, 20, 2}],
  Take[x, {21, 50, 3}]
} // Flatten
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 24, 27, 30,
>   33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48}

Or as oneliner

```
Take[x, #] & /@ {{1, 10, 1}, {11, 20, 2}, {21, 50, 3}} // Flatten
```

Same output

Comment: @user2558894 You're welcome

Answer (score 2):

```
x = Array[q, {50}];
```

In addition to `Take` suggested in eldo's answer , you can also use `Part` (`x[[..]]`)

```
Join @@ x[[#]] & @@@ {{;; 10}, {11 ;; 20 ;; 2}, {21 ;; 50 ;; 3}}
(* {q[1], q[2],q[3],q[4],q[5],q[6],q[7],q[8],q[9],q[10],
    q[11],q[13],q[15],q[17],q[19],
    q[21],q[24],q[27],q[30],q[33],q[36],q[39],q[42],q[45], q[48]} *)
```

Or `Extract`

```
Join @@ Extract[x, {{Range[10]}, {11 ;; 20 ;; 2}, {21 ;; 50 ;; 3}}]
(* same output *)
```

See also: [Undocumented form of Extract](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/46261/125)

Comment: Interestingly, the undocumented `Extract` does not work anymore in 10.0.1

Comment: Thank you @RunnyKine, i was just about check that now:)

Comment: @RunnyKine, just tried in v10; it still works exactly as in v9. Note that the extraction list should be prepended with something that does not trigger an error message: `{{}}, or {0} or {{101,4,3}}`, the remainining elements can contain `Span`s.

Comment: I know it works in v10. But it doesn't work in 10.0.1

Comment: @RunnyKine, I see.. I am using Wolfram Programming Cloud. I assumed it runs 10.0.1; perhaps not.

Comment: Interesting that the programming cloud has not been updated.