# "Indexing" a vector

Tags: list-manipulation

I need to "index" a vector according to the first occurence of its distinct elements.

I have written

```
index[list_] :=
 Module[{x = list, p},
  p = Flatten /@ Map[Position[x, #] &, DeleteDuplicates@x];
  Table[x[[p[[i]]]] = i, {i, 1, Length@p}];
  x]
```

which gives the expected result:

```
vec= {1, 4, 4, 8, 7, 7, 4};
index @ vec
```

> {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2}

**(1)** How could a more functional / efficient solution look like?

**(2)** How could such a solution be extended to work with matrices?

ad (2)

```
mat = {{1, 4}, {2, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 4}};
```

should give

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}}

Comment: Thanks for the Accept!  You should revisit this in a future release as I expect `ArrayComponents` will eventually be upgraded to be superior (or at least I hope so).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The old-school way to do this:

```
index[a_] := Module[{i = 1, f}, f[x_] := f[x] = i++; f /@ a]

index @ vec
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2}
> ```

A method using `Assocation`, introduced long *after* `ArrayComponents`.

```
index2[a_List] := AssociationThread[#, Range@Length@#] ~Lookup~ a & @ DeleteDuplicates @ a
```

*Edit #2: extended to matrices using eldo's own method:*

```
index2[m_List?MatrixQ] := Partition[index2 @ Flatten @ m, Last @ Dimensions @ m]
```

halirutan's [`unflatten`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30412/121) could be used in similar fashion for application to arbitrary nested lists of any structure.

#### Benchmarks

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

BenchmarkPlot[{ArrayComponents, index, index2}, RandomInteger[#, 5 #] &, 2^Range[3, 20], 
 "IncludeFits" -> True, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Well then, at least on this first test the older `ArrayComponents` is several times slower than the newer `Assocation` and `Lookup` functionality.  Let's try benchmarks with first denser and then sparser duplication:

```
BenchmarkPlot[{ArrayComponents, index, index2}, RandomInteger[99, 5 #] &, 2^Range[3, 20], 
 "IncludeFits" -> True, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

With dense duplication `index2` still beats `ArrayComponents`.  `index2` is about six times faster than `ArrayCompoents` here.

```
BenchmarkPlot[{ArrayComponents, index, index2}, RandomInteger[15 #, 5 #] &, 
 2^Range[3, 20], "IncludeFits" -> True, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

With sparse duplication `index2` is still the winner, but there is indication that it has higher complexity.  Let's try single point test with a larger set.  (Each in a fresh kernel.)

```
SeedRandom[0]
big = RandomInteger[3*^7, 1*^7];
ArrayComponents[big] // Timing // First
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 23.758952
>
> 2092193592
> ```

```
SeedRandom[0]
big = RandomInteger[3*^7, 1*^7];
index2[a_] := AssociationThread[#, Range@Length@#] ~Lookup~ a & @ DeleteDuplicates @ a
index2[big] // Timing // First
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 13.400486
>
> 1199556824
> ```

Not only does `index2` remain faster than `ArrayComponents` it uses only a bit more than half as much memory.

Alright, a final test: perhaps unpacked data is the Achilles heel of `index2`:

```
(* don't forget to reload definitions needed for this plot *)

BenchmarkPlot[{ArrayComponents, index, index2}, "foo" /@ RandomInteger[#, #] &, 
 2^Range[3, 20], "IncludeFits" -> True, ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Nope! :-)  It appears that `index2` is superior across the board.

Comment: I had to take apart `index2` to see how it worked. A nice touch. +1

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 22):

I think the built-in function `ArrayComponents` is what you need:

```
vec = {1, 4, 4, 8, 7, 7, 4};
ArrayComponents[vec]
(* {1,2,2,3,4,4,2} *)

mat = {{1, 4}, {2, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 4}};
ArrayComponents[mat]
(* {{1,2},{3,4},{4,3},{5,2}} *)

raggedarray = RandomSample /@ (CharacterRange["a", "z"][[#]] & /@ 
              Range[RandomSample[Range[5]]])
(* {{"a","b"},{"a"},{"c","b","a"},{"d","c","b","a"},{"e","b","c","d","a"}} *)
ArrayComponents[raggedarray]
(* {{1,2},{1},{3,2,1},{4,3,2,1},{5,2,3,4,1}} *)

genericinput = {{"a", "b"}, 1, 2, {3, 4}, {"a"}, "c", "b", "a", {"d", "c", "d"}, {2, 3}} ;
ArrayComponents[genericinput]
(* {{1,2},3,4,{5,6},{1},7,2,1,{8,7,8},{4,5}} *)
```

Comment: Should I delete the question? I wouldn't have assumed that there is such an "easy" solution. On the other hand, who knows all of the inbuilt functions?

Comment: @eldo, I think you should keep the question unless a duplicate shows up on this site.

Comment: @kguler thanks...always learning something new, so agree keep if not duplicate

Comment: @eldo The answer is simple but IMO `ArrayComponents` is not easy to find in the documentation.  This should remain open.

Comment: @eldo I argue for the superiority of a different method.  Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you very much. I will try to "digest" your answer(s) tomorrow, "take [them] apart" as rcollyer commented. Of course, speed considerations are important.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Your `index3` delivers wrong results. I would prefer a dual definition: `index[m_?VectorQ] := 
 AssociationThread[#, Range@Length@#]~Lookup~m &@DeleteDuplicates@m` and then `index[m_?MatrixQ] := Partition[index@Flatten@m, Last@Dimensions@m]`

Comment: @eldo In what way does it deliver wrong results?  You mean when the input is not a matrix?  Nice idea by the way but I think the partitioning may be slower; I'll have to test it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard (a) `index3[{{1, 4}, {2, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 4}}]` just returns the input: `{{1, 4}, {2, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 4}}`. (b) I conducted your benchmark tests with my `Partition`-proposal, and it's still extremely fast.

Comment: @eldo Oops! I'll fix that.  Or I could just replace it with your suggestion; do you mind that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Please replace with my proposal

Answer (score 4):

you can also use `ClusteringComponents` function

```
inex[m_] := ClusteringComponents[m, Length@m + 1];

vec = {1, 4, 4, 8, 7, 7, 4};
inex[vec]
(*{1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2}*)

mat = {{1, 4}, {2, 7}, {7, 2}, {9, 4}};

inex[mat]
(*{{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}}*)
```

Comment: Unfortunately this scales very poorly due to the clustering overhead: `BenchmarkPlot[{ArrayComponents, ClusteringComponents[#, Length@# + 1] &}, RandomInteger[#, 5 #] &, 2^Range[3, 20], "IncludeFits" -> True, ImageSize -> 600]` yields http://i.stack.imgur.com/u5SOg.png

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here's a way to do it without using the built-in function:

```
Clear[firstP]
firstP[l_List] := l /. MapIndexed[#1 -> First@#2 &, DeleteDuplicates[Flatten@l]]

firstP /@ {vec, mat}
(* {{1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2}, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {4, 3}, {5, 2}}} *)
```

Comment: Interesting, but your results don't agree with kguler's (and the examples in my question)

Comment: Sorry I mistakenly thought you wanted something different. It also becomes easier to solve.

Comment: If you add `Dispatch` around the list of rules this is pretty competitive in Mr.Wizards benchmark. [Graph](http://i.stack.imgur.com/vk2MG.png). +1