# Adding list of list to a list

Tags: list-manipulation

Hello I need some help on how to add a list to a list of list. The program would have to do as below:

```
{{0,0}, {0}, {0,0,0}}+{1,2,3,4,5,6}
```

will give

```
{{1,2}, {3}, {4,5,6}}.
```

Could this be done? Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: No it doesn't it will give me the second list.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: Do you wish to "add" the first list to the second or to partition the second list to have the structure of the first?  It appears you mean the latter.  Also, please explain your comment as it relates to the question.  Thanks.

Comment: @bbgodfrey i want to partition the second like the first

Comment: @bbgodfrey not at all. In fact, I deleted my comment.

Comment: I see that this question has accumulated three Close votes in favor of [(23395)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23395/121).  While that question *sounds* similar I don't believe Simon's method can be applied to this problem.  If it can please show me, otherwise I shall contravene closure.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without testing whether there are as many elements in the first list as there are in the second, the solution is as simple as

```
listAdd[structured_, flat_] := Module[{i = 1},
  Function[elm, elm + flat[[i++]], {Listable}][structured]
]

listAdd[{{a, b}, {c}, {d, e, f}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]
(* {{1 + a, 2 + b}, {3 + c}, {4 + d, 5 + e, 6 + f}} *)
```

To understand why this works, please study carefully my answer [of this question.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/30412/187)

Comment: This is elegant and flexible but it comes at the cost of performance: more than two orders of magnitude slower than `add` in the "Like/Long" test I just posted.

Answer (score 6):

## Performance comparison

Here is a performance comparison of all methods given in the order of their posting.

Bill's code is not self-contained so I shall use:

```
bill[a_, b_] := 
 Module[{h, list = b}, 
  Map[(h = Take[list, Length[#]]; list = Drop[list, Length[#]]; # + h) &, a]
 ]
```

The other functions for ease of execution:

```
add[a_List, b_List] := a + dynP[b, Length /@ a]

listAdd[structured_, flat_] := 
 Module[{i = 1}, Function[elm, elm + flat[[i++]], {Listable}][structured]]

raggedMap = Internal`PartitionRagged[#1[Flatten[#2], #3], Length /@ #2] &;

listAdd1[structured_, flat_] := Module[{cnt = 1, f}, f = Function[x, x + flat[[cnt++]]];
  Map[f, structured, {-1}]]

deFlatten[flat_, reference_] := 
 Module[{cnt = 1}, Replace[reference, elem_ :> flat[[cnt++]], {-1}]]

listAdd2[structured_, flat_] := deFlatten[Flatten[structured] + flat, structured]
```

Yi Wang's `listAdd3` threw errors so I did not include it in this test.

Generating code for two lists of the like type (Integer) with short sublists:

```
Needs["GeneralUtilities`"]

a = RandomInteger[9, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 5000];
b = RandomInteger[9, Length@Flatten@a];

bill[a, b]             // AccurateTiming
add[a, b]              // AccurateTiming
listAdd[a, b]          // AccurateTiming
raggedMap[Plus, a, b]  // AccurateTiming
listAdd1[a, b]         // AccurateTiming
listAdd2[a, b]         // AccurateTiming
```

Like-types and long sublists:

```
a = RandomInteger[9, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 500}, 500];
b = RandomInteger[9, Length@Flatten@a];
```

Unlike types and short sublists:

```
a = RandomInteger[9, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 5000];
b = RandomChoice[{"a", "b", "c"}, Length@Flatten@a];
```

Unlike types and long sublists:

```
a = RandomInteger[9, #] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 500}, 500];
b = RandomChoice[{"a", "b", "c"}, Length@Flatten@a];
```

A table of results:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This question is similar to [7511](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/7511/partitioning-with-varying-partition-size), which was solved with

```
dynP[l_, p_] := MapThread[l[[# ;; #2]] &, {{0}~Join~Most@# + 1, #} &@Accumulate@p]
```

In your case, `dynP[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6},{2, 1, 3}]`, where the second list is the lengths of the desired partitions, gives the answer.  If, on the other hand, you wish to work from your template list, use

```
dynP[[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, Length /@ {{0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}}]
```

As a function:

```
add[a_List, b_List] := a + dynP[b, Length /@ a]
```

Now:

```
add[{{2, 3}, {5}, {7, 11, 13}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]
```

> ```
> {{3, 5}, {8}, {11, 16, 19}}
> ```

Comment: Exactly how I would do it. +1  (And thanks for linking the source.)  I added an example; I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Not at all, @MrWizard.  Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

IF listoflist is only nested one level deep then

```
listoflist = {{0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}};
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
Map[(h = Take[list, Length[#]]; list = Drop[list, Length[#]]; # + h) &, listoflist]

(* {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5, 6}} *)
```

Answer (score 3):

Two ways to use `` Internal`CopyListStructure ``:

```
addLsts1 = # + Internal`CopyListStructure[#, #2] &;

addLsts1[{{a, b}, {c}, {d, e, f}}, Range@6]
```

> ```
>  {{1 + a, 2 + b}, {3 + c}, {4 + d, 5 + e, 6 + f}}
> ```

`addLsts1` is as fast as Mr.Wizard's `add`.

A slower alternative:

```
addLsts2 = Internal`CopyListStructure[#, Flatten[#] + #2] &;

addLsts2[{{a, b}, {c}, {d, e, f}}, Range@6]
```

> ```
> {{1 + a, 2 + b}, {3 + c}, {4 + d, 5 + e, 6 + f}}
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
raggedMap = Internal`PartitionRagged[#1[Flatten[#2], #3], Length /@ #2] &;
raggedAdd = raggedMap[Plus, #, #2] &;
```

Usage examples:

```
raggedAdd {{0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]
```

or

```
raggedMap[Plus, {{0, 0}, {0}, {0, 0, 0}}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}]
```

both give

```
(* {{1, 2}, {3}, {4, 5, 6}} *)

lst1 = {{a, b}, {c}, {d, e, f}}; 
lst2 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
raggedAdd[lst1, lst2]
(* {{1+a, 2+b}, {3+c}, {4+d, 5+e, 6+f}} *)

raggedMap[Times, lst1, lst2]
(* {{a, 2 b}, {3 c}, {4 d, 5 e, 6 f}} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

**Using `TakeList`:**

```
alist = {{a, b}, {c}, {d, e, f}};
blist = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

alist + TakeList[blist, Length /@ alist]
```

> {{1 + a, 2 + b}, {3 + c}, {4 + d, 5 + e, 6 + f}}

Also:

```
alist TakeList[blist, Length /@ alist]
```

> {{a, 2 b}, {3 c}, {4 d, 5 e, 6 f}}

Answer (score 1):

One solution: map at the last level

```
listAdd1[structured_,  flat_] := Module[{cnt = 1, f},
  f =  Function[x, x + flat[[cnt++]]];
  Map[f, structured, {-1}]]
```

Another solution: First define a function `deFlatten[flat, reference]`, to undo Flatten, according to a given reference list:

```
deFlatten[flat_, reference_] := Module[{cnt = 1},
  Replace[reference, elem_ :> flat[[cnt++]], {-1}]]
```

For example,

```
deFlatten[{a, b, c}, {1, {2, 3}}]
```

> {a, {b, c}}

Then it is trivial to implement `listAdd`:

```
listAdd2[structured_, flat_] := 
 deFlatten[Flatten[structured] + flat, structured ]
```

A third solution, by keeping the position of the list in `MapIndexed`, and restore the position using ReplacePart

```
listAdd3[structured_, flat_] := Module[{f}, ReplacePart[structured, 
  Flatten @ MapIndexed[f, structured, {-1}] + flat /. n_ + f[m_, pos_] :> (pos :> m + n)]]
```