# Positions of elements in the initial flattened list in a split list

Tags: list-manipulation, sequence

Say, we have a list:

```
m1 = {2, 2, 7, 0, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2}
```

It can be split easily:

```
Split @ m1
(* {{2, 2}, {7}, {0}, {7, 7}, {2, 2, 2}}  *)
```

**Wanted**: a method to get the following list:

> `{{1, 2}, {3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}`

It should be as simple as possible and fast for long lists.

Comment: Related: [(3585)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3585/121), [(23607)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23607/121), [(69906)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/69906/121)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use

```
SplitBy[Range@Length@m1, m1[[#]] &]
```

Comment: Immortal [solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/21344/24604)

Comment: so clean and nice +1 :-)

Comment: +1 Looks useful. Is there some way to illustrate how this works?

Comment: As discussed [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23623/24604), `Split` and `SplitBy` are very slow for long list. I've tried it with `m1 = Flatten[Table[#, # + 1] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10^5]];` and it is order of magnitude slower that counterparts.

Comment: How it works: see output `list = {}; SplitBy[
 Range@Length@m1, (AppendTo[list, #]; m1[[#]]) &]; list` plus [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SplitBy.html) `SplitBy[list,f]` *splits list into sublists consisting of runs of successive elements that give the same value when f is applied.*

Answer (score 9):

There is a complicated trade-off between the speed and compact form in this case, so I have decided to post the version with `Range`, which I consider simple enough (comprehensible for new users) and second fast among the conterparts (at least, on my machine).

It is heavily based on @Mr.Wizard solution farsightedly provided by ChrisDegnen, so I do not claim originality:

```
dynS[p_] := Range @@@ Thread[{Accumulate@p - p + 1, Accumulate@p}]
```

---

### Method

And after looking at @Mr.Wizard `SparseArray` solution I finally realize that we may use `Listable` attribute of `Range` to get even more compact version (this time I would prefer to keep pure function notation `#`). So this is **favorite method** for me (not mine :)!

> `dynSP[p_] := Range[# - p + 1, #]& @ Accumulate @ p`

---

### Timing benchmarking

I use the long list for benchmarking:

```
m1 = Flatten[Table[#, # + 1] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 200}, 10^5]];
Length[m1]
(* 10156647 *)
```

And packed version later (second timing output in each method).

```
m1 = Developer`ToPackedArray[m1];
```

---

```
Range[Prepend[# + 1, 1], Append[#, Length @ m1]] & 
@ SparseArray[Differences @ m1]["AdjacencyLists"] // Length // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.403, 99530} *)
(* {0.274, 99489} *)

dynSP[Length /@ Split @ m1] // Length // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.476, 99439} *)
(* {0.626, 99439} *)

dynS[Length /@ Split @ m1] // Length // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.506, 99495} *)
(* {0.715, 99489} *)

Internal`PartitionRagged[Range[Length@m1], Length /@ Split@m1] // Length // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.589, 99495} *)
(* {0.78, 99489}  *)

dynP[Range@Length@m1, Length /@ Split @ m1] // Length // RepeatedTiming
(* {0.613, 99495} *)
(* {0.83, 99489}  *)

Module[{i = 1}, Replace[Split@m1, _ :> i++, {-1}]] // Length // RepeatedTiming
(* {3.845, 99439} *)
(* {4.1, 99439}   *)

Module[{i = 0}, Map[++i &, Split[m1], {-1}]] // Length // RepeatedTiming
(* {6.57, 99495} *)
(* {6.85, 99489} *)

SplitBy[Range @ Length @ m1, m1[[#]] &] // Length // RepeatedTiming
(* {24.6, 99495} *)
(* {25., 99489}  *)
```

*Note*: fastest function with `SparseArray` has been added a bit later so its result in terms of length is slightly different. The same is for the `Module` with `Split` version and my favorite `DynSP`.

Answer (score 8):

Perhaps:

```
s = Split@m1;
Internal`PartitionRagged[Range[Length@m1], Length /@ s]
```

Comment: oh, nice, I've missed such possibility, thank you. [Related](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83124/24604)

Answer (score 7):

`` Internal`CopyListStructure `` is quite fast:

```
Internal`CopyListStructure[Split @ #, Range @ Length @ #] & @ m1
```

> ```
>  {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
> ```

Comment: thank you, I did not know about this structure. Upvoted a couple of similar questions.

Answer (score 6):

Too late for the party so here's something old style:

```
Module[{i = 0}, Map[++i &, Split[m1], {-1}]]
```

or

```
SplitBy[MapIndexed[Flatten@*List, m1], First][[;; , ;; , 2]]
```

Comment: it is never too late to make a good contribution. I like the old style...

Answer (score 5):

Using Mr.Wizard's ragged partition function [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/7512/363)

```
dynP[l_, p_] := MapThread[l[[# ;; #2]] &,
  {{0}~Join~Most@# + 1, #} &@Accumulate@p]

m1 = {2, 2, 7, 0, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2};
m2 = Split@m1;

dynP[Range@Length@m1, Length /@ m2]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}

Comment: ,thank you, ironically I saw this solution a year ago but was incapable to grasp it :))

Answer (score 5):

```
m1 = {2, 2, 7, 0, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2};
Module[{i = 1}, Replace[Split@m1, _ :> i++, {-1}]]
(* {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}} *)
```

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I remember warnings concerning `Block`, so never use(d) it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. That's interesting. I should go read the use cases for different scoping constructs post again.

Comment: march, using `Block` incorrectly seems to get a lot of people; as stated I did it myself many times before more experienced users (Szabolcz or Leonid probably) pointed out my mistake.  Even [Wolfram developers do it!](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3589/121) Using his code on `numbering[{{a, b}, {m, n}, {x, y}}]` for example note that `n` has been *incorrectly* replaced by `0` in the output.

Answer (score 4):

Adapted from [my answer to a related question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/23623/121):

```
runs[a_List] := 
 Range[Prepend[# + 1, 1], Append[#, Length@a]] &@
  SparseArray[Differences@a]["AdjacencyLists"]
```

Now:

```
runs @ {2, 2, 7, 0, 7, 7, 2, 2, 2}
```

> ```
> {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}}
> ```

Comment: Oh, `SparseArray`!!! I was about to ask how to apply it here :)))

Comment: @garej Glad I could be of help. :-)  Please add this to your benchmark.

Comment: @garej I see that a new syntax has been added for `Table`, after version 10.1.0 (which I use).  Anyway (at least in 10.1) your `m1` is not packed; would you please try your benchmark also with ``m1 = Developer`ToPackedArray[m1];`` ?

Answer (score 3):

I'll add another option, but be warned: It's rather slow.

```
FoldPairList[TakeDrop, Range@Length@m1, Length /@ (Split @ m1)]
```

Comment: yes, it hangs my machine with `m1 = Flatten[Table[#, # + 1] & /@ RandomInteger[{1, 100}, 10^5]];` but it nice to have it here. It is as slow as using new `SequencePosition` ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
SplitBy[Transpose[{m1, Range@Length@m1}], First][[;; , ;; , -1]]
```

or

```
m2 = Range@Length@m1;
i = 1; Split[m2, m1[[j = i++]] === m1[[j + 1]] &]
```

Comment: thank you, `{14., 99530}` for the first method, but I cannot check the second one.

Comment: you can check it like this `Module[{m2 = Range@Length@m1,i=1},Split[m2, m1[[j = i++]] === m1[[j + 1]] &]]`

Comment: `{24., 99496}` in my machine , that is too long !!! ):-

Answer (score 3):

Just wanted to belatedly add a new-style spin on Kuba's classic old-style answer, using the [`"Counter"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/datastructure/Counter.html) [`DataStructure`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DataStructure.html)

```
With[{counter = CreateDataStructure["Counter", 1]},
 Map[counter["Increment"] &, Split[m1], {2}]]
(* {{1, 2}, {3}, {4}, {5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}} *)
```