# Matrix indexed by one number

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

I'm trying to find a generic way (for arbitrary dimensions) to create a matrix like so

```
a[1] a[2]

a[3] a[4]
```

i.e where it is indexed by one number, instead of say `Array[a, {2, 2}]` which gives

```
a[1,1] a[2,1]

a[2,1] a[2,2]
```

I hope you can help!

Answer (score 17):

`Partition[ Array[a, 4], 2]` will do it.

In general,

```
makeMat[n_, m_] := Partition[ Array[a, n*m], m]
```

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I sought for. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 6):

With a little indexing arithmetic, one can use only `Array[]` to generate the required matrix:

```
With[{m = 4, n = 4},
     Array[C[n (#1 - 1) + #2] &, {m, n}]]
   {{C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4]}, {C[5], C[6], C[7], C[8]},
    {C[9], C[10], C[11], C[12]}, {C[13], C[14], C[15], C[16]}}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
matF1 = Partition[# /@ Range[#2 #3], #3] &
matF2 = ArrayReshape[Array[#, Times[##2]], {##2}] & (* thanks: J.M. *)

{matF1[a, 2, 3], matF2[a, 2, 3]}
```

> { {{a[1], a[2], a[3]}, {a[4], a[5], a[6]}},
>         {{a[1], a[2], a[3]}, {a[4], a[5], a[6]}}}

```
matF2[a, 2, 3, 2]
```

> {{{a[1], a[2]}, {a[3], a[4]}, {a[5], a[6]}},
>         {{a[7], a[8]}, {a[9], a[10]}, {a[11], a[12]}}}

Comment: Hm, is there really a good reason to use `Map` and `Range` instead of combining them into a single `Array` call like Szabolcs did?

Comment: @MartinBüttner, not really:) - just another way.

Comment: Alternatively: `matF2 = ArrayReshape[Array[#, Times[##2]], {##2}] &` This more general form can now yield tensors instead of just matrices: `matF2[a, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: @J.M. great point, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Another method,

```
makeMat[n_, m_] := 
 Map[a, Array[#2 &, {n, m}] + m Range[0, n - 1], {2}]

makeMat[4, 5] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: As always, I am indebted to you for spotting my mistakes  :-)

Comment: :) Now I can upvote. Here is a slot-free version: `makeMat[n_, m_] := 
 Map[a, ConstantArray[Range[m], n] + m Range[0, n - 1], {2}]`

Answer (score 3):

It's like the opposite of [code-golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/),

```
With[
 {n = 3, m = 5},
 mat = ConstantArray[1, {n, m}];
 i = 1;
 For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
  For[k = 1, k <= m, k++,
   mat[[j, k]] = a[i];
   i++;
   ]
  ];
 ]
mat // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: My word... use `Do[]`, for the love of heaven! :P

Comment: Well, this was a tongue-in-cheek post, I could delete it if those aren't really welcome here

Comment: Does the date today have anything to do with why you posted this? ;)

Comment: Oh dear lord, today is the day to look skeptically at the internet isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

```
    n = 4;
    lst = Table[a[i], {i, 0, n}]
    A = Partition[lst, n/2] // MatrixForm

    a[1]    a[2]
    a[3]    a[4]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way that works with arbitrary dimension arrays, without using a dummy counter index:

```
SparseArray[MapIndexed[# -> a[First@#2] &,
     Sort[Flatten[MapIndexed[ #2 & , #, {-1}],
       Depth[#] - 2]]]] &@Array[0&, {2, 4, 2}]
```

[image]

even play with `SortBy` to tweak the ordering:

```
SparseArray[MapIndexed[# -> a[First@#2] &,
     SortBy[Flatten[MapIndexed[ #2 & , #, {-1}],
       Depth[#] - 2], {#[[1]], #[[3]], #[[2]]} &]]] &@
  Array[0&, {2, 4, 2}]
```

[image]

and a variant that works with arbitrary lists:

```
ReplacePart[#,
   MapIndexed[# -> a[First@#2] &, 
    Sort[Position[#, x_ /; AtomQ[x], Heads -> False]]]] &@
 {{0, {0, 0, 0}}, {0, 0, {0, 0}}}
```

> {{a[1], {a[4], a[5], a[6]}}, {a[2], a[3], {a[7], a[8]}}}

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take (although I would have actually done it [Szabolcs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/12/szabolcs)'s [way](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/111633/29734)).

```
mat = {{f, "x"}, {1, Sin[23]}}
Module[{i = 1}, Replace[mat, _ :> a[i++], {2}]]
(* {{f, "x"}, {1, Sin[23]}} *)
(* {{a[1], a[2]}, {a[3], a[4]}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

One more way:

```
ClearAll@a
Block[{i = 1}, Array[a[i++] &, {3, 4}]] // MatrixForm
```

Comment: This is in the same spirit as march's answer.

Comment: Is there a reason to use Block instead of Module here?
Somewhat related, why doesn't using Module here prevent the introduction of the name `i` into the global namespace?  I would have expected that difference.

Comment: @Alan. Actually, one *shouldn't* use `Block` here. [I've been "chastised" about that before.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/104763/29734).

Comment: One other question: this approach depends on the array being filled in row-major order.  This is currently true, but is it documented/guaranteed?