# How do I create a n*n matrix with a Do loop?

Tags: functions, matrix, inputfield

I'm trying to create an n*n matrix that would follow this criteria

```
1    2    3   ...  n
n+1  n+2  n+3 ...  2n
2n+1 2n+2 2n+3 ... 3n
 .                  .
 .                  .
 .                  .
(n-1)n+1 ........ n^2
```

How would I be able to create this matrix using a table or a do loop?
This is what I've created so far, but it doesn't follow the criteria unfortunately.

```
n = Input["What positive integer would you like to start your matrix with?"];
x = ConstantArray[0, {n, n}];
Do[x[[i, j]] = i + j, {i, 1, n}, {j, 1, n}]
x // MatrixForm
```

Comment: Why not use `Partition[Range[n^2], n]`?

Comment: you didn't like the answers over here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/42240155/1004168 ?

Comment: This is a version of [(111631)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/111631/121)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Better to use `Table`:

```
n = Input["What positive integer would you like to start your matrix with?"];

Table[i + j*n, {j, 0, n - 1}, {i, n}]
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you define a function, `m` to create your matrix. Here are two possible for `m`

Carl Woll

```
m[n_] := Partition[Range[n^2], n]
```

m_goldberg

```
m[n_] := ArrayReshape[Range[n^2], {n, n}]
```

In either case

```
m[3]//MatrixForm
```

[image: matrix]