# Find range of same number in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have this list:

```
a={1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,6,6,6,6,7,7,7,7}
```

Now I would like to create a list with the ranges of positions of all same numbers, hence:

```
range = {{1,4},{5,9},{10,13},{14,17},{18,21}}
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Should be `{5,9}`, right?

Comment: hmm, this is almost it: [104672](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/104672/5478) only one step is missing to drop inner positions `#[[;;, {1,-1}]]&`.

Comment: @Kuba Thanks for spotting the typo !

Comment: For the sake of having different ways of doing it, just because... you could also use `Transpose@{Most[# + 1], Rest[#]} &@
 DeleteDuplicates@Accumulate@BinCounts[a]`,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7};

SplitBy[Transpose[{#, Range@Length@#}], First][[;; , {1, -1}, 2]] &@a
```

> ```
> {{1, 4}, {5, 9}, {10, 13}, {14, 17}, {18, 21}}
> ```

Comment: Awesome work ! Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 7):

```
Values[PositionIndex[a]][[All, {1, -1}]]
```

> {{1, 4}, {5, 9}, {10, 13}, {14, 17}, {18, 21}}

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution based on [this old gem](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/1992/Nov/msg00096.html):

```
# + {1, 0} & /@ Partition[FoldList[Plus, 0, Length /@ Split[a]], 2, 1]
   {{1, 4}, {5, 9}, {10, 13}, {14, 17}, {18, 21}}
```

Comment: 1992?!?!  does J.M stand for Jhonny Mnemonic?

Comment: You would think... ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
list = 
  {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7};
```

Using `SequencePosition` (new in 10.1)

```
SequencePosition[list, {a_, a_ ..}, Overlaps -> False]
```

{{1, 4}, {5, 9}, {10, 13}, {14, 17}, {18, 21}}

**Addendum**

As lericr commented it might be better to use `Repeated`. To show the difference we prepend a `0` to `list`:

```
list = {0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7};

SequencePosition[list, {a_, a_ ..}, Overlaps -> False]
```

{{2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 8}, {9, 12}, {13, 14}}

```
SequencePosition[list, {Repeated[a_]}, Overlaps -> False]
```

{{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 8}, {9, 12}, {13, 14}}

Comment: `SequencePosition[a, {Repeated[x_]}, Overlaps -> False]` might be better, as it works with "singleton" sequences, e.g. `{1,1,1,2,3,4,4...}`. Of course, we don't know whether that's relevant in OP's situation.

Comment: Thank you, lericr, I updated the answer with your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

```
list = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7};
```

Another way is to use `Position` and `MinMax`:

```
Function[x, MinMax@Position[list, x], Listable]@Union@list

(*{{1, 4}, {5, 9}, {10, 13}, {14, 17}, {18, 21}}*)
```

Or using `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[list, {a_ ..} :> MinMax@Position[list, a]]

(*{{1, 4}, {5, 9}, {10, 13}, {14, 17}, {18, 21}}*)
```

The above approach with `SequenceCases` works very well if the list is not of type `{1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7}`, but in the latter case we must add `DeleteDuplicates`, as pointed out by @eldo.

Comment: +1, but I would use `DeleteDuplicates` (to see what I mean, exchange 2s and 1s)

Comment: Interesting observation. By interleaving 2 and 1 up to position 9 and leaving the rest unchanged, we must apply `DeleteDuplicates` and one of the lists with odd positions is for 1 and the other list with even positions is for 2. This is more general, I like it. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"];
a = {1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 6, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7};

b1 = {0}~Join~a // Differences // Unitize // Position[#, 1] & // 
  Flatten

b2 = Length /@ Split[a] // Accumulate
Transpose[{b1, b2}]
```

> {{1, 4}, {5, 9}, {10, 13}, {14, 17}, {18, 21}}