# How to reshape a list as another ragged list

Tags: list-manipulation

#### Background

If I want wo reshape `list1` as `list2`:

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
list2 = {{7, 4}, {1, 7}, {7, 6}};
```

We can use `ArrayReshape` and `Dimensions` to do it.

```
ArrayReshape[list1, Dimensions[list2]]
```

> {{1, 2}, {3, 4}, {5, 6}}

#### Question

But when the `list2` is a ragged list,how to do such thing with **elegant method**?

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
ragList = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, {5, 6}, 7}, {8}, {{{9}}, 10}};
```

Comment: Try using *Flatten*.

Comment: @L.K. I mean how to make `list` to be `ragList` as its dimension

Comment: @andre Do mind post it as an answer?

Comment: I cast my close vote for the wrong question; I meant to mark this as a duplicate of [(30405)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30405/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's hard for me to find those relevant post.I'm very sad about this every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this :

```
list = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
ragList = {{a, b, c}, {d, {e, f}, g}, {h}, {{{i}}, j}};

i=1;
Map[list[[i++]]&,ragList,{-1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

Curent method:

```
reshape[list_, ragList_] := 
 Module[{pos = Position[ragList, _?NumericQ, Infinity]}, 
  ReplacePart[ragList, Thread[pos -> list]]]
```

Usage:

```
reshape[list, ragList]
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, {5, 6}, 7}, {8}, {{{9}}, 10}}

#### Performance

Function `andre` from this [comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/138031/how-to-reshape-a-list-as-another-ragged-list/138032#comment372639_138031)

```
andre[list_, ragList_] := 
 Module[{i = 1}, Map[list[[i++]] &, ragList, {-1}]]

MyPlot[{reshape @@ # &, 
  andre@@ # &}, {Range[#], 
   MapAt[List, Range[#], 
    List /@ RandomSample[Range[#], RandomInteger[#]]]} &, 11]
```

[image]

Ps:My `MyPlot` is `MyPlot:=BenchmarkPlot[##1,IncludeFits->True]&`

Answer (score 2):

```
template = {{a, b, c}, {d, {e, f}, g}, {h}, {{{i}}, j}};
replist = Evaluate[(ReplacePart[template,
     Rule @@@ Transpose[{
        Reap[MapIndexed[Sow@#2 &, template, {-1}]][[2, 1]],
        Slot /@ Range@Length@Flatten@template}]] )] &
```

> {{#1, #2, #3}, {#4, {#5, #6}, #7}, {#8}, {{{#9}}, #10}} &

```
list = Range@10;
replist@(Sequence @@ list)
```

> {{1, 2, 3}, {4, {5, 6}, 7}, {8}, {{{9}}, 10}}

Comment: But how to get your `ragList`?

Comment: On the other hand, if you will be doing this reshaping for many lists but the same ragList, then something along these lines might be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the elements in ragList are unique, this would work as well:

```
ragList /. Map[#[[1]] -> #[[2]] &, Transpose[{Flatten[ragList], Flatten[list]}]]
(* {{1, 2, 3}, {4, {5, 6}, 7}, {8}, {{{9}}, 10}} *)
```